# Simple guessing program in Python with while loop

Tags: python

```
has_guessed = False
number = 9

while not has_guessed:
    answer = int(input("Guess: "))
    if answer == 9:
        print("You won")
        has_guessed == True
```

It states that "has_guessed == True" seems to have no effect.

Comment: With `has_guessed == True` you're not actually assigning `True` to the loop control variable `has_guessed`, instead the statement `has_guessed == True` is an evaluation, which indeed is having no effect. To assign the value `True` to the variable `has_guessed`, just write this: `has_guessed = True`

Answer (score 3):

It is correct since `has_guessed == True` is a comaprison operation that return True or False. Use `has_guessed = True` to assign True to the `has_guessed` variable.